# How to scale out a system which do database query intensively?

Tags: database, system-design, data-synchronization

I'm designing a multi-tenant system which has roughly about 100 tenants. What we want to archive is to sync data with another system with the frequency 1 minute, there are many info to sync so i splitted them up into 5 background job (Menu, Employee, Order, Table, Heartbeat).
The tenant's data is put separately in a database, so 100 tenant -> 100 database. So far, i have 1 master background job to orchestrate everything and 100 slave background jobs. Each one does the syncing stuff for an individual tenant.

The syncing flow goes like this (Query to get all the records that changed -> mapping to 3rd model -> perform http request to 3rd party service to sync up the changes).

I insisted the other team to publish a message everytime they make changes to the data so we don't have to query everything everynow and then but that's not the solution since their codebase is legacy and the changes would not be approriate at this point.

One more thing i think i should bring up here, all the database is put inside an Elastic Pool.

What if the number of tenant goes up to 200, or the products goes up to something like 2M products? What is the overhead in this design? Any suggestion or even any other design to reduce the query frequency to make the system healthier?

Comment: Putting a http request in the middle of your replication is really going to slow things down. Any reason you want to put a web API in the middle of all this? You can always move a database out of elastic pool and into dedicated, or have a couple of pools to help with processing if you run out of juice. You also need to optimise your database with suitable indexes etc. You might find at this scale that you are going to have to invest in a more solid platform ie.. synapse (I assume elastic pool = Azure)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid i use the http request to sync the data to the 3rd party service. Yup, we are using Azure here. Just want to reduce the cost and resource if there's some overhead

Comment: Luckily if you find you have provisioneda tier that is under utilised you can easily scale it down. The hard part is setting expectations around cost. A 100 tenant system with replication and analytics is not going to be cheap.